# How to implement a helper accessible from an ember component's template

Tags: ember.js

I've written a component to 'wrap' a semantic-ui 'dropdown' ui element.

Within this 'dropdown' I need to use a #link-to to generate a link that will 'fire' when a row is selected.  I would like to define a helper that would allow me to manipulate the string that would otherwise be the dropdown menu row's visible content.  A concrete example would be capitalizing the string.

How do I do this ?

Thanks
Dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Helpers are accessible in all templates. Unless I am missing something this is as simple as:

```
Em.Handlebars.helper('capitalize', function(string) {
  return string.capitalize();
});
```

And in your components template, something like:

```
<ul>
  {{#each dropDownItems}}
    <li>{{#link-to link}}{{capitalize text}}{{/link-to}}</li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

Of course the exact template depends on how your component is structured.

`capitalize()` is a method available on `Em.String` throughout your app.

You can read more about [Ember helpers here](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/writing-helpers/).

Comment: Thanks for the response - but it still doesn't work.  Here's a gist link with the relevant details -> https://gist.github.com/anonymous/fed20d5248e2f118eaa1.  In short - I tried adding the helper as you suggested and using it from my components template - but it didn't work.  Any suggestion(s) on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: [Here is a working JS Bin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/zeyenijiwolu/1/edit?html,js,output). You didn't specify `App` in the component class name but otherwise your code works fine. What's not working?

Comment: I'm using ember-cli - so I don't think its correct to preface 'App'.   There were actually two things I was doing wrong ...

1) if you want 'helpers' to be 'auto recognized' their names need to contain a '-'
1a) if you want your 'helper' to be just one word - it needs to imported in app.js
2) within the helper - you can't access the string directly, it has to be escaped.

The name of my app is 'inventory'.  Here's the relevant import statement ...

import "inventory/helpers/capitalize";

and to access the string ...

var str = Ember.Handlebars.Utils.escapeExpression(string);

Comment: Ok, you should put info like that in your question as that changes the answer. Ember-CLI documents how to format your helpers [here](http://www.ember-cli.com/#helpers) so just follow that syntax and name your helper something like `capitalize-string`. Are you still having trouble?

Comment: Nope - got the helpers working nicely now.  I will be sure to be more specific next time.  Thanks